# Low Search Fuzzy Search Questions

Tags: search, low-search, low

I've got Low Search working in a site thats using keyword and a separate category filter menu.

The client has pointed out that when he searches for...

> Director - Product appears (As is in 'Title') 
>   
> Directors - Product doesn't appear
>
> Robens - Product appears (As is in 'Title')
>   
> Roben - Product doesn't appear

I've got this current setup...

```
{exp:low_search:form
    result_page="shop/search"
    form_class="form-inline"
    collection="shop_product"
    keywords:lang="en"
    keywords:inflect="yes"
    keywords:loose="both"
    keywords:mode="all"
    keywords:stem="yes"
    search_mode="any"
}
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="I'm looking for...">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Find" class="button alternate">
        </li>
    </ul>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

But I feel like I'm adding too many parameters in for this to work. I've read through numerous docs and form/stackexchange posts and still can't seem to get this working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params):

> [P]arameters can be applied in two ways: as input fields in a Form, or as hard-coded parameters in the Results or URL tag.

You've got the filter parameters set on the Form tag, which will have no effect (as [per v3.0](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs#to-3.0), anyway). You should move all those parameters (except `result_page` and `form_class`, which are valid [Form tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-parameters) parameters) to the Results tag.

Also, make sure you're running [version 4](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/changelog#v4.0.0) at least, as the inflection and stemming rules were added in that version.

Finally, I'd recommend *not* using `keywords:loose="both"` *unless* you're searching a language that has no spaces as word delimiters, like Chinese or Thai.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't see that in the docs as I was looking in the filters bit. Will make that switch. The site is running 2.5.3 and can't be updated at the moment.